# D3 Styles Not Being Applied

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to produce a bar chart using d3 but I cannot seem to properly apply the styling. I import the data using d3.dsv(...) and then call

```
.then(function (data) {
      d3.select("body").selectAll("div")
        .data(data)
        .enter()
        .append("div")
        .styles({
          'width': '5px',
          'background-color': 'teal',
          'margin-right': '2px'
        })
        .style("height", function (d) {
          return d.total_amount + "px"
        });
```

I can see that there is a new div being created for each element in data but none of the styling is being applied. I've looked through some of the other posts here but I still don't see what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Do you see any errors in the console? That's something to learn to start checking. It might show that the right method is `style`, not `styles`.